# Prove expression is not prime

Tags: induction

$$
(n + 4)^4 + 4
$$

If n is natural number, how to prove that above expression is not prime?

I am stuck here

$$
(n+4)^2 \cdot (n+4)^2 + 2 . 2
$$
$$
\left(\left(n^2+4^2\right) \cdot 2\right)\left(\left(n^2+4^2\right) \cdot 2\right)
$$

Comment: Firstly, it's an expression, not an equation. Secondly, your factorization is flawed -- try multiplying it back to see. But the expression _does_ factor. It's a well known trick. Hint: $x^4+4 = (x^2+2)^2 - 4x^2$.

Comment: if $n=-3$ then the above expression evaluates to $5$ which is prime. Do you mean that $(n+4)^2 . (n+4)^2 + 2 . 2 = (n^2+4^2 . 2)(n^2+4^2 . 2)$, could you prove this, can't you show it is not valid, and why do you need it? Use computer algebra: $(n^2+10n+26)(n^2+6n+10)$.

Comment: @Mirko n is natural number. I will edit my question.

Comment: Try n = 2 and you have a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context of the question, I assume $n ≥ 0$.
Clearly for even $n$, $(n+4)^4+4$ is even. Hence suppose $n$ is odd, so $n = 2k+1$. Then $(n+4)^4+4 = (2k+5)^4+4 = 16 k^4 + 160 k^3 + 600 k^2 + 1000 k + 629 = (4 k^2 + 16 k + 17) (4 k^2 + 24 k + 37)$.

Clearly this is composite, as for $n≥0$, this is a product of two natural numbers greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write
a more general form
as the difference of two squares
which we know how to factor.

$\begin{array}\\
x^4 + a
&=(x^2+u)^2-b^2x^2\\
&=x^4+2ux^2+u^2-b^2x^2\\
&=x^4+(2u-b^2)x^2+u^2\\
\text{and}\\
x^4 + a
&=(x^2+u+bx)(x^2+u-bx)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$u^2=a$
and
$b^2 = 2u$.

Therefore
$b^4 = 4u^2
= 4a
$.

Writing $c^2$ for $a$,
this becomes

$\begin{array}\\
x^4 + c^2
&=(x^2+u)^2-b^2x^2\\
&=x^4+2ux^2+u^2-b^2x^2\\
&=x^4+(2u-b^2)x^2+u^2\\
\text{so}\\
u
&=c\\
\text{and}\\
x^4 + c^2
&=(x^2+c+bx)(x^2+c-bx)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$b^2 = 2c$.

Since $b$ and $c$
are integers,
$c = 2d^2$
and
$b^2 = 4d^2$
so $b = 2d$.

Therefore,
the expression can 
only be factored
if it is of the form
$x^4+4d^4$
when the factorization is
$x^4+4d^4
=(x^2+2d^2)^2-4d^2x^2
=(x^2+2dx+2d^2)(x^2-2dx+2d^2)
$.

This is the case
$d=1$
so $b=2$
and the factorization is
$x^4+4
=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)
$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $(x+4)^4+4=0$ has roots $x = -4 \pm \sqrt{\pm 2i}=-4 \pm (1 \pm i)\,$, so the expression factors as: $$(x+4)^4+4=(x^2 + 6 x + 10) (x^2 + 10 x + 26)$$